# Spymemcached handling node for operation is not set

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I have a simple code that is supposed to work with memcached. Unfortunately, it is not working properly.

Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
MemcachedClinet memcached = new MemcachedClient(new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
                    .setDaemon(true)
                    .setFailureMode(FailureMode.Cancel)
                    .build(),
                AddrUtil.getAddresses("192.168.178.27:11211"));

memcached.get(keyName);
```

Here is an error I get during execution:

```
2014-08-28 01:47:46.577 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/192.168.178.27:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-28 01:47:46.579 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  handling node for operation is not set
28-Aug-2014 01:47:46.579 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] com.internetlogisticsinc.projects.xenu.core.Rotator.getCounter null
 java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Cancelled
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:177)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:69)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1230)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1257)
(...)
```

I have completely no idea what `handling node for operation is not set` means what can cause this error message. Memcached server works properly and I can connect to it with telnet without any problems. The telnet test was done on the same machine as where application is running.

Googling for `handling node for operation is not set` did not bring me any helpful results.

The code is executed as a servlet in Apache Tomcat 8.0.3, bundled into NetBeans 8.0. Spymemcached version is 2.11.4.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

First check you whether you can connect your server using simple Java class using basic connection. First set a value and then try to retrieve it.

```
MemcachedClient c=new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("hostname", portNum));
```

This exception may be thrown in multi nodes memcache configuration when you are not configured nodes correctly.

Comment: I have updated my code with your code and the results are series of:

Comment: `2014-08-28 12:30:49.571 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/192.168.178.27:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue

2014-08-28 12:30:49.572 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for com.example.test.
`

Comment: Are you using single memcached node or multiple nodes? It seems to be it is configured with multiple nodes but actually you have one node.

Comment: I use only a single node